# Reference for stochastic calculus with jumps

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

All the standard books I know on stochastic calculus work almost exclusively with continuous martingales. What are the standard references for the general theory (with jumps)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned only continuous martingales, note that it is also possible to define stochastic calculus using local martingales and semimartingales.

Some textbooks which cover the more general theory are:

- Limit Theorems for Stochastic Processes by Jacod & Shiryaev
- Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations by Protter
- Stochastic Integration Theory by Medvegyev
- Stochastic Integration with Jumps by Bichteler
- Stochastic Integrals by Welzsäcker & Winkler

Personally, I like the textbook by Medvegyev since it contains more (worked) examples, however it doesn't contain any exercises.

Answer (score 1):

Try Philip E. Protter's  "Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations"